# Spring Security, time before logout

Tags: spring, spring-security

I don't know why, maybe I write wrong code. My website  does   logout  after a while.
I wrote in

```
application.properties
session.timeout.interval = 350000000 and 
session.setMaxInactiveInterval = (60*60*24)
```

in form HTML I wrote

```
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post"
  authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler">
```

My code in Spring Security:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/cars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()

                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

            httpSecurity.rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me")
            .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400000);



    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new MyPasswordEncoder();
    }




@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

I try use  httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class) but I see logout again

Comment: i guess you should specify the session length in the web.xml too

Comment: I havn't web.xml, all that is need write in application.properties